# Uploading Videos using ckeditor in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, video-streaming, carrierwave

I am using ckeditor "4.0.4" with carrierwave and Active Record.

Its fine while iam uploading images and embed videos from youtube.

But i stuck when i am uploading videos from local machine. It is storing that images in public/ckeditor/attachements/model but it is not displaying any content in show.

How can i play that videos?

And in my rich description i need to differentiate everything. please tell me the easiest way to do that?

```
config.js

    { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image','Iframe','Flash','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar' ] },

new.html.erb

 <%= f.cktext_area :description %>
```

while playing attachments the uploaded video converting to embed tag like

```
<object height="252" width="425" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000">
<param value="black" name="bgcolor">
<param value="high" name="quality">
<param value="transparent" name="wmode">
<param value="showall" name="scale">
<param value="/uploads/ckeditor/attachments/5/at_school_10_sec._video.3gp" name="movie">
<embed height="252" width="425" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="/uploads/ckeditor/attachments/5/at_school_10_sec._video.3gp" scale="showall" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" bgcolor="black">
```

but it is not playing any video showing some empty place only.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you post your code? or what you tried?

Comment: check it now i am using ckeditor iframe and for storing attachments i am using carrierwave\